# Energy is in vacuum or not?

Tags: energy, vacuum

Is energy present in vaccum is zero, infinity or particular value depending on volume, length, height etc of container containing vaccum or some other parameter.

Answer (score 1):

According to the current and successful Lambda-CDM model of cosmology (which has a level of acceptance among cosmologists similar to that of the Standard Model among particle physicists), the energy density of the vacuum is $5.4\times10^{−10}$ joules per cubic meter. So it isn’t zero, and it isn’t infinite. There is a particular value for the vacuum energy per unit volume. This is the energy density when there are no real particles of any kind: no atoms or molecules, no protons, no neutrons, no electrons, no photons, no neutrinos, etc.

To get the vacuum energy in any container, multiply this energy density by the volume of the container.

This energy is called “dark energy” and its origin is unclear. (One possibility is that it comes from virtual particles, but this explanation is currently very problematic, to put it mildly.) Cosmologists believe that it is making the universe expand faster and faster rather than slower and slower. The density of dark energy is believed to stay constant as the universe expands, which is its most peculiar property.

This idea of a constant vacuum energy density goes back to Einstein’s “cosmological constant”. In General Relativity, it is mathematically a very natural thing to have. He initially put it into his equations, then took it out. Now it’s back, in order to explain the observed acceleration of the expansion of the universe. It explains other things as well, such as the details of the angular fluctuations in the temperature of the cosmic microwave background. Without it, we can’t explain our cosmological observations.

The only effect of dark energy is believed to be gravitational, and it only becomes important on the scale of the universe.

Comment: According to quantum field theory the vacuum energy is incredibly large. This conflicts with observation. This is known as the cosmological constant problem. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant_problem

Comment: And some supersymmetric theories predict it to be zero, I believe. But from the standpoint of GR, there don’t have to be *any* quantum fields to have vacuum energy. And it can be interpreted in a way that it really isn’t even energy, but just behaves as if it is.

Comment: Sure, but these are not mainstream, like QFT.

Comment: Supersymmetric theories are just QFTs with a particular symmetry. They are entirely mainstream. Mainstream does not mean “accepted based on experimental confirmation”. It means “accepted as respectable but speculative physics”. We have no idea whether supersymmetry holds at high energies. We simply haven’t seen it at low energies. And even models which are completely ruled out can still be mainstream physics.

Comment: Without QFT we would have a big hole in our explanation of nature. Without sypersymmetry we just have one hobby less. The fact that SUSY predicts zero vacuum energy does not offset the absurd prediction of QFT.

Comment: @safesphere It would he peculiar in GR *not* to have a cosmological constant, as it is simply the zeroth-order term in the Einstein-Hilbert action, in powers of the curvature Why would the action have a first-order term but not a zeroth-order term?

Comment: @safesphere I fully agree with your account of the ZP energy. I think this is what Casimir and Polder also believed. Is this published anywhere?